# I do not want a debian interface

Tags: debian, cinnamon, interface

Today I set up an old portable pc to be a dedicated machine

I have installed debian and at installation process I have chose Cinnamon for graphical interface

Now my system is configured and working fine

I want to have access to this machine only with ssh and I dont want to have access to Cinnamon or every type of interface to keep every performance in process and not for graphique

It's possible to do that ?

Comment: Of course. Just ssh in to it.

Comment: and for disabling interface ? ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable X server autostart in Debian Jessie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264393/how-to-disable-x-server-autostart-in-debian-jessie). Also applies to Debian 9.

Answer (score 2):

Debian 8 and 9 use `systemd` as the default init system, so the commands needed to disable the GUI interface immediately & persistently are:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

The first command sets the text mode as the new default system state (so it will take effect on next and subsequent boots), and the second command enforces the new state immediately.

To re-enable graphics mode, respectively:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

If you've opted to use the classic SysVinit instead, you'll need to do something like `update-rc.d -f gdm remove ; update-rc.d gdm stop 99 1 2 3 4 5 6`. Replace gdm with whatever display manager you're using: Debian has had at least `gdm`, `kdm`, `xdm`, `wdm` and `sddm`. Unlike most other distributions, Debian did not separate runlevel 3 for text mode and 5 for GUI mode.