# How can I not remove but disable xfce?

Tags: x11, xfce

I'm trying temporarily switch between dwm and xfce. When using dwm, I would just run it from the ~/.xinitrc script, but with xfce it's more complicated. When I installed xfce it completely took over and I can't even see the login shell (I'm just prompted to log into xfce). How can I disable xfce (not remove), so I can run it whenever I want ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264393/how-to-disable-x-server-autostart-in-debian-jessie), you could try running
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
to disable the X server at startup, and run
`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` to resume starting the X server on boot.